# Can't type characters in git bash

Tags: windows, git, bash, git-bash

I just rebooted and re-installed `git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0` and rebooted again on my Windows 7 pro 64bit.
And I can't type the letters <kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>r</kbd> in the git bash. I can type <kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd>( capitalized )

[image: These are not the letters you are looking for]

I tried changing the font size, edit mode and dir but it keeps happening.
I tried using alt codes too, but those don't seem to work in this bash screen.

I'm flabbergasted, What can I do to resolve this ?

Comment: Have you checked ~/.inputrc ?

Comment: Aha, .inputrc contains some code to enable auto complete in python console. removing it fixes this problem, but now i can't do auto complete in python :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frequently there are key mappings defined in `~/.inputrc` that can redefine the shell's interpretation of the keys.

Comment: ... let's finish this answer. It contains no information that would help with the troubleshooting.